# WPF Inkcanvas Draw and Rotate Shapes

Tags: wpf

I want to know how to rotate and move the shapes which are drawn on inkcanvas in wpf. I am using VS 2015 and working on a project named WhiteBoard. On that board I am using Inkcanvas, which is used to draw and erase shapes like circles, rectangles etc.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can rotate or move the entire InkCanvas. Check this:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="RotateTransformStoryboard">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="inkCanvas" From="0" To="359" BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:05"
                             RepeatBehavior="1" 
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(RotateTransform.Angle)" >
            </DoubleAnimation>

        </Storyboard>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource RotateTransformStoryboard}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Window.Triggers>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>


        <InkCanvas Grid.Row="0" x:Name="inkCanvas" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <InkCanvas.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="0" />
                </TransformGroup>
            </InkCanvas.RenderTransform>      
        </InkCanvas>
        <Button x:Name="btn1" Content="transform" Grid.Row="1" Height="30" />
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Hey Newton Zou , i donot want to Rotate the entire Inkcanvas ,instead of this i want to rotate the inkcanvas child using mouse,like after select the shape and Rotate the shape.Please review this issue and provide me better Solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: If the children are some controls added in code like buttons and textbox, it can be selected and rotate. But if they are drawn by the user in run time, it can't. You need implement by yourself.

Comment: Ok thanx for the help.